# Can't figure out why I'm getting `Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found` in a django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates, python-3.7

The project has 2 apps - accounts (very basic custom users) and portal.

myproject/myproject/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import urls
from portal import admin as user_admin
from portal import views


urlpatterns = [
    urls.path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    urls.path(r'portal/mymodel/', views.testview),
    urls.path('', user_admin.user_site.urls),
]
```

myproject/portal/templates/portal/mymodel/testview.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block after_field_sets %}{{ block.super }}
    <h2> hello world </h2>
{% endblock %}
```

change_list.html (built-in django template):

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_list %}

{% block extrastyle %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/changelists.css" %}">
  {% if cl.formset %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/forms.css" %}">
  {% endif %}
  {% if cl.formset or action_form %}
    <script src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
  {% endif %}
  {{ media.css }}
  {% if not actions_on_top and not actions_on_bottom %}
    <style>
      #changelist table thead th:first-child {width: inherit}
    </style>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
{{ media.js }}
{% endblock %}

{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} app-{{ opts.app_label }} model-{{ opts.model_name }} change-list{% endblock %}

{% if not is_popup %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% translate 'Home' %}</a>
&rsaquo; <a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=cl.opts.app_label %}">{{ cl.opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a>
&rsaquo; {{ cl.opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}

{% block coltype %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div id="content-main">
    {% block object-tools %}
        <ul class="object-tools">
          {% block object-tools-items %}
            {% change_list_object_tools %}
          {% endblock %}
        </ul>
    {% endblock %}
    {% if cl.formset and cl.formset.errors %}
        <p class="errornote">
        {% if cl.formset.total_error_count == 1 %}{% translate "Please correct the error below." %}{% else %}{% translate "Please correct the errors below." %}{% endif %}
        </p>
        {{ cl.formset.non_form_errors }}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="module{% if cl.has_filters %} filtered{% endif %}" id="changelist">
      <div class="changelist-form-container">
        {% block search %}{% search_form cl %}{% endblock %}
        {% block date_hierarchy %}{% if cl.date_hierarchy %}{% date_hierarchy cl %}{% endif %}{% endblock %}

        <form id="changelist-form" method="post"{% if cl.formset and cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %} novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
        {% if cl.formset %}
          <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        {% block result_list %}
          {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
          {% result_list cl %}
          {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
        </form>
      </div>
      {% block filters %}
        {% if cl.has_filters %}
          <div id="changelist-filter">
            <h2>{% translate 'Filter' %}</h2>
            {% if cl.has_active_filters %}<h3 id="changelist-filter-clear">
              <a href="{{ cl.clear_all_filters_qs }}">&#10006; {% translate "Clear all filters" %}</a>
            </h3>{% endif %}
            {% for spec in cl.filter_specs %}{% admin_list_filter cl spec %}{% endfor %}
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

myproject/portal/templates/portal/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def testview(request):
    return render(
        request, 'portal/mymodel/testview.html', {'app_label': 'portal'}
    )
```

and the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 76, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 130, in get_response
response = self._middleware_chain(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
response = response or self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
response = response or self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
response = response or self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
response = response or self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
response = response or self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
response = response or self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__
response = response or self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 49, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 114, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/myproject/portal/views.py", line 8, in testview
return render(
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
return template.render(context, request)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
return self.template.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
return self._render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
return nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 86, in reverse
return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/(?P<app_label>portal|auth|accounts)/$']
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Stupid beginner mistake? Also if there's other code that may be relevant here please let me know and I can provide it.

Edited to add:
The higher level issue here is that MyModel has a field called user. When a user views the MyModel changelist, they need to only see the MyModel objects that reference them, and should not see the MyModel objects that reference other users.

Comment: Maybe add what `change_list.html` looks like? Also your question formatting is a bit messed up with the code in the middle.

Comment: my fault, just fixed it

Comment: You are not passing a context variable named `cl`, so `cl.opts.app_label` is an empty string.

Comment: Yeah does the error go away or change if you comment out `{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=cl.opts.app_label %}` or change it to `{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=app_label %}`

Comment: @getup8, this is a built-in template so to edit it directly would be to edit the site-packages files for the django installation... @Selcuk, I'm not sure I understand how to pass that in the context dictionary... I tried this:
```
return render(
        request,
        'portal/mymodel/testview.html',
        {'app_label': 'portal', 'cl': {'opts': {'app_label': 'portal'}}}
    )
```

but it failed with:
```
'File "/Users/me:D/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'opts'
```

Comment: I guess you might want to update your question with what you're actually trying to do / build. You're trying to display an admin template (an extension of one) with a bare bones view that sends basically nothing to the template so I'm not sure it really makes sense. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites

Comment: @getup8 I'll update my question too, but the issue is that MyModel has a field called user. When a user views the MyModel changelist, they need to only see the MyModel objects that reference them, and should not see the MyModel objects that reference other users.

Comment: Got it. Yeah I think you're better off just asking a question on that perhaps. Guessing you've read this page? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/ There's something called "RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter" but not sure whether it's what you need.

Comment: Not quite what I need but I was going to be looking into how to add those types of filters next so thank you! However it's working as I needed now after overriding get_queryset(self, request) in the ModelAdmin subclass I have for MyModel.

Answer (score 7):

First, you are using a view outside of the admin, which is fine, but you are using an admin template `change_list.html` which assumes some variables sent out with the template context. I would suggest to add custom urls to your `admin.py` (see bellow), and send the necessary context so the template is rendered properly.

I had the same issue, which was caused in this line:

`<li><a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}">{{ opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a></li>`

When looking on the context provided to the template with `django-debug-toolbar` I noticed that the `opts` variable was not being sent. In your case, the culprit is probably `cl`.

So I had to update my custom urls code and sent it myself:

```
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        opts = self.model._meta
        custom_urls = [
            url(
                r'^(?P<some_id>.+)/actions/task_start/$',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(SomeCustomFormView.as_view(
                    extra_context={'opts': opts}
                )),
                name='task_start',
            ),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls
```

The `cl` variable is got from the request:
`cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)` and sent out with the context like this (`django/contrib/admin/options.py`):

```
context = {
            **self.admin_site.each_context(request),
            'module_name': str(opts.verbose_name_plural),
            'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
            'selection_note_all': selection_note_all % {'total_count': cl.result_count},
            'title': cl.title,
            'subtitle': None,
            'is_popup': cl.is_popup,
            'to_field': cl.to_field,
            'cl': cl,
            'media': media,
            'has_add_permission': self.has_add_permission(request),
            'opts': cl.opts,
            'action_form': action_form,
            'actions_on_top': self.actions_on_top,
            'actions_on_bottom': self.actions_on_bottom,
            'actions_selection_counter': self.actions_selection_counter,
            'preserved_filters': self.get_preserved_filters(request),
            **(extra_context or {}),
        }
```

But you don't have easy access to the request in `get_urls` so I would change the template code and instead of using `cl` I would use `opts` which I get from the model meta field.